# How can I convert the font-size in UIlabel to the font-size in UIwebView

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a `NSString` with font-size 16 in `UIlabel`. And I want to show this `NSString` in `UIWebView`  using syntax like font-size = '?' in html. And I want to the font-size in the `UIWebView` is corresponding to the font-size in `UIlabel`. How can I do this?

Comment: I use CGSize labelSize = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:UILinearModeWordWrap]; NSInteger *lines = labelSize.height / 18 to get the lines of my string. How can I show the string in UIWebView within the same lines number?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a NSString which contains html code, then load UIWebview from the NSString with the method

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

In html you can set the font of text, which one you want.

Comment: I use CGSize labelSize = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:UILinearModeWordWrap]; NSInteger *lines = labelSize.height / 18 to get the lines of my string. How can I show the string in UIWebView within the same lines number?

Comment: I don't really understand why do you calculate lines of text? If you set label.numberOfLines = 0; it makes the job for you. For web; you can make any layout using html (maybe also css). You just need to set the same width, font, and line breaking mode. Then it should look similar.

Comment: Because my webview is a subview of a tableviewcell. Although my webivew can auto resize by the way you said, my tableview cell's height cannot auto resize. So I want to use the lines to estimate the height of the cell ahead. In addtion, did you say the font having the font-size 16 in html is similar to the font having the font-size 16 in UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

you must concatenate your string with the html setting the font size like this
`[yourWebView loadHTMLString:@"<p><font size="5">put your text here</font></p>" baseURL:nil];`

Comment: I use CGSize labelSize = [string sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:size lineBreakMode:UILinearModeWordWrap]; NSInteger *lines = labelSize.height / 18 to get the lines of my string. How can I show the string in UIWebView within the same lines number?